Foundry: Order of `setUp()` function and fuzz runs of a fuzz test?
Based on this file:
// SPDX-License-Identifier: UNLICENSED
pragma solidity >=0.8.26 <0.9.0;

import { PRBTest } from "@prb/test/src/PRBTest.sol";
import { StdCheats } from "forge-std/src/StdCheats.sol";
import { Vm } from "forge-std/src/Vm.sol";

contract Debug is PRBTest, StdCheats {
  uint256 private _someNr;
  /** The setUp() method is called once each fuzz runs is perfomred.*/
  function setUp() public virtual {
    _someNr=5;
  }


  function testFuzzDebug(uint256 randomValue) public virtual {
    assertEq(_someNr, 5); 
    _someNr=6;
  }
}

I conclude that it is ran before each fuzz run of a fuzz test (consisting of a thousand fuzz runs).
However, in another case, I create a temp.txt file that is removed in the setUp() function, and later on in that same setUp() if it does not yet exist, it is created, and the timestamp 1726940006 of the last time of modification of that temp.txt file is taken as the folder name for a file in which the fuzz test results are stored. This results in a single timestamped directory for a 1000 fuzz runs, like: 1726940006. (I would expect a thousand timestamps, one for each fuzz run of a fuzz test). I am happy it works, but I currently do not exactly understand why it works.
Hypothesis I
A hypothesis could be that the 1000 fuzz runs are completed within the maximum timestamp granularity, e.g. within a second. However, after increasing it to 100000 I can see the 1726940006/log_output.txt file being updated over a span of multiple (~40) seconds. Still only one 1726940006 directory is created.
Hypothesis II
The setUp() function is called 1000 times, the 1000 results of running the setUp() function are stored somewhere, and then, when they are all done, each of the 1000 fuzz runs are ran on the accompanying setUp() function.
Question
Is thesetUp() function ran 1000 times before the (each of the accompanying fuzz test runs 1000 fuzz runs? Or does it go:

1st call to setUp() function, 1st fuzz run of a fuzz test
2nd call to setUp() function, 2nd fuzz run of a fuzz test
...
1000st call to setUp() function, 1000th fuzz run of a fuzz test
?
Or something else?

